# Where is the user agent version / string?

Tags: php, user-agent

So in my php code i got this :

```
<?php
$UserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo "$UserAgent";
?>
```

and the output in `INTERNET EXPLORER` is this :

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET     CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
```

but my question is, where's the user agent string or version or something kinda like that .. 
Sorry for my bad english ..
NB : I'm very new at PHPs code, So its normal that if i didn't know that

Comment: That **is** the user agent string.

Comment: @Dencker you mean is `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET     CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)` this ?

Comment: Yes, that is the UA string :)

Comment: @Dencker ok thanks for helping =D

Comment: How did you even find that command and not know what it does?

Comment: @Epodax Funny story, but i thought that mozilla or 4.0 is the UA String. well i know the command from my book, but it doesn't show the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're getting is the User-Agent header from the current request.

You can use this value with the `get_browser()` to get what the user's browser is capable of:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

You'll get everything parsed and ready to use like the browser, the version, the platform, etc.

You can find more informations regarding this function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).